# how to get clicked element from multiple class in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am polluting a div with the help of following codes every time the 'Add' button is clicked on the website.

```
const addClick = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addClick.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addNote();
});

function addNote(){
    const notes = document.getElementById("notes");
    notes.innerHTML += `
    <div class="note">
    <div class="delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></div>
    <button class="save"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
    <textarea type="text" class="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    `;
 }
```

With this code, I am generating note(s) that has delete or save options. I want to know which class element was clicked. I want to do this with vanilla Javascript.

[image]

Comment: You can use ```event.target``` to distinct which note was clicked

Comment: Add an event listener on the parent element and utilize event propagation to catch the child that was clicked like so `note.addEventListener('click', (e) => {const clickedEl  = e.target}`

Comment: What value is in the note? @BlackMath

Comment: I used onclick=function(event) but it wasn't working for some reason when I implemented it through .innerHtml

Comment: @KrzysztofPodmokły

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I meant `notes.addEventListener(...)`

Comment: @BlackMath Worked like magic.. Thank you so much for your help. I was first trying to do this with class but since all class names are same I had to give each note Ids and then catch that unique Id to know which note was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use event delegation:

add an event listener to the parent element or document and then check if the clicked element contains the class that you want to target.

You may need to also check if the element clicked is a child of the button (the icon)

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var target = event.target;
    if (isElement(target, 'delete')) {
      console.log("delete button clicked", target.closest(".note"));
    } else if (isElement(target, "save")) {
      console.log("save button clicked", target.closest(".note"));
    }
});

function isElement(element, className) {
    return element.classList.contains(className) || element.closest(`.${className}`);
}
```

```html
 <div class="note">
    <button class="delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Delete</button>
    <button class="save"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Save</button>
    <textarea type="text" class="text"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="note">
    <button class="delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Delete</button>
    <button class="save"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Save</button>
    <textarea type="text" class="text"></textarea>
</div>

<div class="note">
    <button class="delete"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>Delete</button>
    <button class="save"><i class="fas fa-check"></i>Save</button>
    <textarea type="text" class="text"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I was able to achieve this using event.target finally.  I am also using firebase for db. Thanks a  lot.

Comment: I had to give unique Id to each new note generated and with the help of event.target I was able to catch that particular id and do the job. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet for your case.

***HTML***

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

***JS***

```
const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>JS Starter</h1>`;

[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach((el, index) => {
  const note = document.createElement("div");
  appDiv.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", note);
  note.classList.add("note");
  note.addEventListener("click", () => {
    appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>Box number: ${index + 1}<h1>`;
  });
});
```

***CSS***

```
.note {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.note:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you for this solution I wasn't able to exactly implement this with my requirement but as you mentioned in the comments I was able to achieve it with the help of e.target once I gave them unique Ids. Thanks a lot for your time really appreciate it.